parametrize allocation in a class
I want to define a test class and apply a parametrize decorator to the class, such that  all test methods in the class are fed the parameters. I also want to be able to apply the parametrize decorator to specific methods in the class so that certain test methods have additional test runs.
@pytest.mark.parametrize("pytest_parameters",[
       pytest.param( [ {'key1' : '3' , 'key2' : '5'}] , id="apple")   
    ])     
class TestClass:
    def test_one(self,pytest_parameters):
        print(pytest_parameters)
    
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("pytest_parameters",[
       pytest.param( [ {'key1' : '5' , 'key2' : '10'}] , id="pear")
    ])
    def test_two(self, pytest_parameters):
        print(pytest_parameters)
        

I have tried this but I get an error.
E   ValueError: duplicate parametrization of 'pytest_parameters'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_x.py::TestClass - ValueError: duplicate parametrization ...

How do I allocate some tests to all methods and a subset of tests to particular methods in a class ?
Any help will be appreciated !!

FYI: Your line above test_two is missing a closing ]).

thanks @LokiRagnarok. I created the  code example just for the question, and the one which I am using has some private info. I believe the issue is related to the duplicate parametrisation. thanks again nonetheless

you just need to rename your second reference to something other than pytest_parameters

thanks @TeejayBruno. I am not sure that is in line with I am trying to do. I want to all methods to execute the base set of tests (that marked above the class), and to have some method to execute the case set of test plus those a set of tests marked above the method
